# PHP - Warning: Illegal string offset and strange output

Tags: php, arrays

I was just playing with PHP array

```
$arr = array(); 
$arr['a'] = 'hello';
$arr['a']['b'] = 'world';
var_dump($arr);
```

This code gives the following error in PHP 5.5.15

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'b'
```

I can guess the reason. (As `$arr['a']` is not an array). Thats fine.

But i am confused by the output,

```
array (size=1)
  'a' => string 'wello' (length=5)
```

Where is this `wello` coming from ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because

```
(int)'b' === 0
```

`'b'` is silently casted to integer (after the warning was printed) and `$arr['a'][0]` sets the first symbol of string to what it could—to the first byte of given string, which is apparently `'w'`.

Answer (score 3):

`$arr['a']` already exists as a string

`$arr['a']['b']` is therefore referencing offset `b` in a string

Characters in Strings can be referenced using array-style syntax as though they are an array of characters, so `$arr['a']['b']` is trying to reference a character in the string at `$arr['a']`

Offsets in a string are numeric; `b` is not numeric, hence the warning

PHP is forgiving, and will cast `b` to a numeric (0) so that it can access a character in the string

So character `0` in the string becomes the first character of the value you assigned (`world`)

So `hello` becomes `wello`

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty simple! You can access the string in your array as an array so:

```
echo $arr["a"][0]; //Output: h
```

So with the index 'b' it's just get's casted to a int, so it takes 0 and overwrites it with 'w'

You even see this example in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

And a quote from there:

```
<?php
$a    = 'car'; // $a is a string
$a[0] = 'b';   // $a is still a string
echo $a;       // bar
?>
```